# Trouble accessing svg path attributes

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am working with html5, js & css3.

I have the following code:

HTML

```
<object id="bottom" data="img/model/skirt.svg"
title="bottom" type="image/svg+xml" width="325"
height="500"> </object>
```

JS

```
var b = document.getElementById("bottom");
b = b.getSVGDocument().getElementById("here");
alert(b);
```

, which gives me "object SVGPathElement".

But when I try to access the fill property I get an "undefined" message.
`alert(b.fill);` for example.

The fill property is definitely set in the svg file. I'm obviously missing something though. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: How do you know that the fill property of that particular element is set?

Comment: I set the id="here" on the path element in question, its a unique id within that svg file and fill="#666666" in that path element. Its a good question, but I checked it thoroughly :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to access SVG properties with `svgEl.setAttribute(name, value)` and `svgEl.getAttribute(name)`.

There is no shortcuts for accessing properties like `HTMLElement`.

But if you really want, you can extend `SVGElement.prototype`:

```
Object.defineProperties(SVGElement.prototype, {
  fill: {
    get: function() {
      return this.getAttribute('fill');
    },
    set: function(value) {
      return this.setAttribute('fill', value);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: For properties (such as `fill`) it's also possible to use the CSS OM, e.g `elm.style.fill` (if the fill is in inline style) or `window.getComputedStyle` - see http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle.

Comment: @ErikDahlström is it the difference between setting the SVG *fill* attribute (in xyiaoyi's case), and changing the *style* attribute's fill property? Which one would have priority? Not sure from [Mozilla's article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes)

Comment: @TheRedPea yes, that's right. A `style` attribute wins over a corresponding `fill` attribute in terms of css [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity), also see [presentation attributes](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/styling.html#PresentationAttributes).